# How to get visual c++ lib file icon back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, icons, shared-libraries

I have installed a program that work with files that have ".lib" extension. So, after installation a new icon appeared on the VC++ (2010 Express) generated static lib files also. Since, it is so annoying, i uninstalled the above program. But it didn't restore previous VC++ icons for lib files. So, how to get those icons back?

Comment: go to file association and select icon you want. You can do it in registry

Comment: @T.S., please tell me how?

Comment: go to your `lib` file, right click, select "properties" and see where it says "opens with" - should say, microsoft visual studio. If that is no help, you can type in Win Explorer `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs` and go to associate a file type or protocol with a program

Comment: @T.S., Then it took Visual studio icon. but i want lib file icon (don't know which application) like this http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jianghui/browser/getting_started/image004.jpg (Icon that has gear wheel...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default program as The Visual Studio, then restart the computer